# Implement a "like this" button in Django without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm attempting to replicate the "like project" feature used in [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/A_B_Testing) (the heart button).

When you click the "like" button, it adds that project to your liked projects list, but it doesn't refresh the page in doing so. The html for the button contains just a link:

```
<a href="/projects/vanity/like" class="icon ... liked" id="like_1953"></a>
```

So, I would really like to know two things.

**(1)** How does this button work?

**(2)** How do I replicate it using Django? Alternatively, if this isn't possible, how should I do it?

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here comes [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). When you need to update the content of a page without reloading the page, ajax is the solution. How does it work in Django? It depends. In a complex case, `render_to_response` and `jquery.load(url)` are really practical. In your simple case, you only need to send an ajax call to one of your view, read the answer and update the DOM element accordingly.

The button is a trap. I can't find the javascript in the page, but surely there's some JS controlling these links. They at least need to:

- Update the link's image on `hover`, changing or toggling class, or directly setting image's url.
- Read the link id and keep only the string after 'like_', which will represent the object's primary key in the database.
- Send an Ajax request to the server, using [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) or any Ajax function. He must be using GET or POST to send the object id.
- Wait for the answer (or not) and update DOM.

How to make it work in Django? Like you would code the normal views!

- Create a normal view with the usual entry in `urls.py`. Code the view as you would do it for a normal Like page. e.g. load user, check if already liked, if not, like, otherwise, unlike. The last line would change though. You could return a json object or just a string using `HttpResponse`, like '0' for 'not liked' and '1' for 'liked'.

There'a recent tutorial [here](http://www.djbp.co.uk/django-poll-tutorial-ajax/) if you need more details.